# ESP32, how can I reply to an http request in 2 (or more) steps?

Tags: http, arduino, esp32, httpserver, arduino-esp32

I need to reply to an HTTP request in some steps (can't concatenate the output string and send it at once).

To illustrate my needs, I do this with PHP on my PC to solve the same problem:

```
<?php
 header("content-type: text/plain");
 echo "20 sensor readings:"; ob_flush();
 for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
   $v = read_sensor(); // takes between 0 to 20 seconds, depending on external events
   echo "time=".time()." value=".$v."\n";
   ob_flush(); // flushes stdout
 }
 echo "end of data\n";
?>
```

With the above example, the data is appended in real-time in the browser.

Using `#include <WebServer_WT32_ETH01>` I didn't find methods to "send the header", "send partial content", "finish the socket". Searched the docs and only found `server.send(...)` which replies at once and closes the TCP socket.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: added the code below explaining better what I need:

```
/* this is a simplified illustrative code for ESP32 httpserver */
#include <WebServer_WT32_ETH01.h>

WebServer server(80); /* use port 80 */

void request_root() {
  server.send(200,
          "text/plain",
          "this is a test");
  /* documentation shows only 2 methods to reply:
   *    send(status,type,content) for sending replies
   *    send_P(status,type,template,parserfunction) for sending replies based on templates */

  /* I used 'wireshark' to debug and the send() function does it all:
   * send the headers, the "empty line" separator, the content, and also closes the TCP socket */

  /* I need some way to send the reply "in some steps" as the above PHP code.
   * didn't find any method at WebServer which allows me to do it */
}

void setup() {
  server.on("/", request_root);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Whether PHP or ESP, [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) work the same. See [the library example](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WebServer_WT32_ETH01/blob/main/examples/WebServer/WebServer.ino#L91-L104) on how the HTTP header is sent followed by the HTTP body.

Comment: @hcheung, the question is about the ESP32 WebServer library. The WebServer_WT32_ETH01 is unimportant for the question. They would have the same problem with the use over WiFi. (OP uses the WebServer_WT32_ETH01 libary because it adds the W5500 as alternative network interface for the ESP32 LwIP and WiFi library so OP can use the bundled ESP32 WebServer library)

Comment: @hcheung the example you pointed uses "WiFiServer", but my project uses "WebServer" which works different. I tried to do a "WiFiClient client = server.available()" as the example does, but I got a "error: 'class WebServer' has no member named 'available'". At WebServer class I only found method "send" which arguments: send(int http_status, char * content-type, char * content) , this "send" method sends everything and closes the TCP socket. I need some method to be able to "do many sends" and a "close" after the last one

Comment: I think you are based on the [AdvancedWebServer](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WebServer_WT32_ETH01/blob/main/examples/AdvancedWebServer/AdvancedWebServer.ino) example, what I'm suggesting is to use the WiFiServer to build your own HTTP however you want over the TCP connection.